# Bug when simulating input change with Enzyme.js - state incorrectly udpated

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I am trying to test input fields in form. However when using `Enzyme.js` to `simulate` change in input field the `state` is incorrectly updated, since the log reveal that `simulate` function has created new record in state named `undefined`.I'd be really glad for help.

Regards

Initial component state looks like this:

```js
this.state = {
    submission: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        date: new Date(),
        validation: {
            email : {isInvalid: false, message: ""},
            firstName : {isInvalid: false, message: ""},
            isValid : true,
            lastName : {isInvalid: false, message: ""}
        }
    }
}
```

This is the testing function:

```js
it('should respond to change event and change the state of the Component', () =>{
    const wrapper = shallow(<ApplicationForm/>);
    console.log(wrapper.find('#firstName').debug());

    wrapper.find('#firstName').simulate(
        'change', {
            target: {
                name: 'firstName',
                value: 'John'
            }
        }
    )

    expect(wrapper.state().submission.firstName).to.equal('John');
})
```

This is what I expect to get in state:

```
submission: {
    firstName: 'John',
    ...
}
```

And this is what I get when I inspect result with `debug`

```
submission: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    date: new Date(),
    validation: {
        email : {isInvalid: false, message: ""},
        firstName : {isInvalid: false, message: ""},
        isValid : true,
        lastName : {isInvalid: false, message: ""}
    },
    undefined: 'John'
}
```

Below you can see the code of the rendered form:

```html
<input type="text"
    id="firstName"
    className="form-control form-control-sm"
    placeholder="First name"
    onChange={this.updateSubmission.bind(this)}
/>
```

updateSubmission function looks as follows:

```
updateSubmission(event) {
    let updatedSubmission = Object.assign({}, this.state.submission);

    updatedSubmission[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        submission: updatedSubmission
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateSubmission` handler uses `target.id`:

```
updatedSubmission[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
```

but in the test you use `name`:

```
        target: {
            name: 'firstName',
            value: 'John'
        }
```

Fixing the test `target` object to use `id: 'firstName'` should fix it. (Or you can switch to using `name` in your code.)